# Changing SwiftUI TextField Values Programmatically

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I have SwiftUI textfield.
I submit same values and process these values in an other class.
According to process in this class I have to replace values in textField with previous data programmatically.

As usual this a pain in swiftUI.
How can I do it ?

Comment: You'd rather need a temporary variable in *other class*, but better provide minimal reproducible example to demo your problem.

Comment: Is there a need for demo I want to change textField values programmatically after textField shown on screen in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it have to be pain.
In UIView textField.text = "" was enough.
I am sure they have their reasons above my grasp.

But while using SwiftUI I did it like that first you put your variables in

```
class Shared: ObservableObject {
static let shared = Shared()

@Published var texEditsDefaults = Edits().defaultValues

}
```

then in process class

```
 class Calculation {

 @ObservedObject var calculation = Shared.shared


   // do something

   texEditsDefaults = newValues

 }
```

and

```
struct TextValuesView: View {
  @ObservedObject var calculation = Shared.shared
   var body: some View {
    ForEach(0..<calcNames.count, id: \.self) { calcIndex in               
      TextField(calcNames[calcIndex], text: $calculation.texEditsDefaults[calcIndex])
         .onSubmit{                                     
           // send values class calculation
         }
       }      
    }
}
```